# What are descriptor registers?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, cpu-registers, osdev

I know what segment registers are. They hold the segment selector (index in the descriptor table + privilege level + local or global table) and, apparently, a hidden part which is also known as 'descriptor cache'. I also understand what Global and Local Descriptor Tables are, and of course, descriptors themselves. However, the [intel 64 and IA-32 architectures software developers manual](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/7c/f1/253668-sdm-vol-3a.pdf#page=95) mentions descriptor register at page 95, volume 3A (chapter 3.4.4 : Segment loading instructions in IA-32e Mode) and this is the first time I heard about them.

> The processor checks that all linear-address references are in
>   canonical form instead of performing limit checks. Mode switching does
>   not change the contents of the segment registers or the associated
>   **descriptor registers**. These registers are also not changed during
>   64-bit mode execution, unless explicit segment loads are performed.

Can any of you explain what descriptor register are?
SS, ES, DS, CS, Es, FS and GS are segment registers, and each entry in the Global and Local Descriptor Tables are called descriptors. What are descriptor registers, then?

I did some research around Google, but nothing appears to answer my question.

Comment: @MichaelPetch "These are hidden/private registers..." More specifically 'a hidden part of the segment registers'. As the intel software developers manual says at the previos page (94 instead of 95): Every segment register has a “visible” part and a “hidden” part. (The hidden part is sometimes referred to as a
“descriptor cache” or a “shadow register.”)

Comment: @MichaelPetch By the way, I like your answer. Would you mind to post it as an actual answer instead of a comment? I would accept and upvote it.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Wait a second. Why does the intel manual says that every segment register has a “visible” part and a “hidden” part if the hidden part is not in the segment register but in the descriptor cache register? Aren't descriptor cache registers a part of the segment registers?

Answer (score 4):

The descriptor registers are more commonly called the descriptor cache.  Rather than reading the appropriate descriptor from the Global or Local Descriptor Tables (GDT/LDT) in memory every time a segment register is used in a memory operand, the descriptors are only read from the GDT/LDT when a segment register is loaded. (Note that all memory operands use a segment register, whether implicitly or explicitly, so if it didn't work this way the CPU would be much, much slower. )

A side effect of this is that's possible to for the descriptor caches not to be sync with the current selectors values loaded in the segment registers.  For example if the LGDT instruction is used to change the address of the GDT, the descriptor cache isn't updated and still contains descriptor values from the old GDT.

The same thing happens when switching modes, like from real mode to protected mode, or from protected mode to long mode (what Intel calls IA-32e Mode).  After the switch from real mode to protected mode the descriptor cache still has the old real mode bases, limits and access rights.  This important because the segment registers also still contain their real mode values which aren't likely to be valid in protected mode.  In particular it allows the next instruction at CS:EIP to be fetched, even though CS contains an invalid selector. The CS descriptor cache still contains valid values pointing to the same place as before the mode change.

The transition from protected mode to long mode works similarly except most of the values in the descriptor cache are ignored in long mode. Instead a fixed base of 0 is used for all segments other than FS and GS, and no limit checks are performed. This means code that switches to long mode should be using a code segment with a base of 0 so the effective CS base doesn't change.

Answer (score 2):

The base / limit and other stuff is permanent until the next `mov ds, whatever`, allowing things like Unreal Mode https://wiki.osdev.org/Unreal_Mode where you switch back to real mode with limit>64k, and usually base=0. (flat 4G).

Intel is describing the segment descriptor caches as a register.  It's just a matter of terminology.

Register is actually a better way to think about it, because "cache" implies that letting it get out of sync with the thing it's caching (the GDT or LDT entry) is bad.

The usual terminology is "descriptor cache", but it's not a coherent cache, and is only intended to change on writes to the segment register, not to memory in the GDT.  (And not updated to reflect changes to the interpretation of segment registers, like real mode vs. protected.)